# Looking for an image gallery webpart - that can do carousel but also when clicked on the image display a popup of the image

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

Looking for an image gallery web part - that can do carousel but also when clicked on the image display a popup of the image.

Any ideas or resources online would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-carousel. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for your prompt response.
Its a good start but what  I was also after is when the image is clicked it should open up a popup of the image

Comment: Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/modal-popup-in-spfx/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854055/how-to-set-a-modal-popup-with-an-image-in-react) for showing popup. You can also try [Dialog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dialog) and [Popup](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/popup) control from Fluent UI library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint out of the box [Image Gallery web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-image-gallery-web-part-bbcbe560-14a7-4369-8ef5-3255845e3bfd) provides carousel functionality but does not display a popup of the image when clicked on image.

Check if below web parts help you in any way with your requirements:

1. [Filterable Image Gallery](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-image-gallery)
2. [Image Slider from Photo Gallery using Taxonomy Filter](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-image-slider-list-taxonomy-filter)
3. [Image Magnifier](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-image-magnifier)

If not, you will have to develop your own custom SPFx web part with required functionality (you can take inspiration/logic from above web parts if you want).

For showing popup/dialog, you can use below Fluent UI controls:

1. [Dialog control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dialog)
2. [Popup control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/popup)

Check below links which might help you with showing dialog/popup:

1. [Modal Popup In SPFx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/modal-popup-in-spfx/)
2. [How to set a Modal popup with an image in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854055/how-to-set-a-modal-popup-with-an-image-in-react)

Comment: Thanks. Will put something together since there is no webpart for it